# HTML CSS Table Design Guidance

Tags: html, css, css-tables

[image: Design]

I am trying to create this type of table or design in HTML/CSS/PHP.

In each block, there will be 3 variables. One with horizontal orientation in center and two with vertical orientation in either direction of a center variable.

I have tried to replicate this by using HTML tables but not getting proper results. This is what I have managed to get.

[image: design]

I already did the programming to configure variables and putting them where they should be with orientation but kind of stuck at proper UI. Kindly help me to design this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in HTML :

```
<table style="width:400px">
<tr>
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td> </td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td> </td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td> </td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Adding in css:

```
th, td {
   padding: 15px;
}
```

Solve It :)

Good luck !!!

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question properly. In one block, only 3 variables, 2 with a vertical orientation and one with horizontal. Your answer is not applicable as per the question. You are new to the community. Please take a look at the guidelines.